# Can Adobe Photoshop Elements 2020 app in the App store construct and print multi month wall calendars?

Tags: calendar, printing, adobe-photoshop

I have an iMac ( 2017 ) running Catalina 10.15. A year and half ago when I was running Mojave I purchased Adobe photoshop Elements 2019 directly from Adobe . The program was very glitchy but did function after a fashion.

When I upgraded to Catalina, Elements got even worse and the only solution Adobe wanted to offer was to get me to pay more money and then to continue to do so.  When I bought Elements 2019 it was not available in the App store and now it is.

My question is this: is the ability to design and print the multipage wall calendars that are part of the Adobe purchased app, still available in the App store version?

Answer (score 0):

Any version of photoshop can be used to print wall calendars. I would probably use Illustrator or another tool, but since you can subscribe to these for a month by month basis - it should be easy for you to decide if it’s worth it or you use a different app.

There’s also a free trial of elements if you want to avoid the full CC apps and go with something you license at fixed cost.

- https://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop-elements.html

Since so few Adobe apps are on the MAS, you might be happier getting it direct from them.

- https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/kb/purchases-mac-app-store-faq.html